# Angular 2 using LocalStorage to keep selection from dropdown list when page refreshes

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I'm trying to get a drop down list to display the selected option when the user refreshes the page. I've got local storage to work to store the value of the current selected option, but I need it to display the selected option after I left the page and came back.

html:

```
<form #languagesSettings="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="languages">Language</label>
        <select (change)="selectLanguage($event)" class="form-control" name="languages" id="languages">
            <option selected = "selected" value="en">English</option>
            <option value="es">Spanish</option>
            <option value="fr">French</option>
            <option value="ru">Russian</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

angular (typescript):

```
public selectLanguage(event: any): void {
        const lang = event.target.value;
        localStorage.setItem('language', lang )
    }
```

Comment: OK, what is the problem? This isn't full code, since we nowhere see how you try and set the value. Please add that.

Comment: All the required code is there, the missing code is what I need. So far the application shows a drop down list, with the populated options and stores the selected option value in local storage. However I don't know how to then retrieve that value and use it to make the drop down list display the selected option after the user has left the page.

Comment: What does "refresh" mean? Just navigating away/back or actually doing a hard refresh?

Answer (score 2):

With all my heart I encourage you to not use local storage for this use case. 
Use a service to store the selected index/option in a public field and call that service in your *ngOninit* to retrieve the values. Run the service as a singleton instance.

This way you will never encounter browser incompatibility problems and will be able to easy distribute stored values across multiple components in the future if need be.

let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: True. Services are indeed the best use in this scenerio

Comment: Its very late but please let us know the code example if you can. Thanks :)